# How are sections rendered in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

Trying to wrap my head around section rendering.

The following

```
\defineheadalternative
  [fullpage]
  [
    alternative=somewhere,
    renderingsetup=headrenderings:fullpage,
  ]

\startsetups[headrenderings:fullpage]
  \startTEXpage % should be enough
    \headtextcontent
  \stopTEXpage
  \page[yes] % stressing the point
\stopsetups

\setuphead
  [section]
  [
    alternative=fullpage,
  ]

\starttext

\chapter{One page one}

\section{This should be on page two}

% should start on the third page
\input knuth

\stoptext
```

produces:

[image]

I would expect `\startTEXpage` or similar to have a page break both before and after it. Or at least `\page[yes]` to push the content to the next page.

Maybe rendering is wrapped in some box? Or is it a constraint of setups? Thanks for any pointer.

---

Edit: to clarify, I'm looking for the spot ConTeXt is introducing this wrapper box.

This is the area in the source I've been exploring:

https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkxl/strc-sec.mkxl?search=strc_sectioning_handle#l877

I'm new to TeX so don't grasp its internals.

Comment: You are inside a box, so you will not get a new page. `\startTEXpage` and `\stopTEXpage` are not meant to be used like this. Maybe in the `\setuphead` add `after={\page[yes]}`. It is a bit unclear what you want to do..

Comment: A save way to to put section titles on a separate page is the use of a makeup-environment, e.g. `\setuphead[section][before={\starttextmakeup[pagestate=start]},after={\stoptextmakeup}]`.

Comment: Thank you! I just want to make sense how it works. :) Looked at the source but unclear where this 'box' comes online: https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkxl/strc-sec.mkxl?search=strc_sectioning_handle#l877 (sorry, new to TeX).

Comment: The code for the section layout resides in [strc-ren.mkxl](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkxl/strc-ren.mkxl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The box is defined as `b_strc_rendering_head` and is populated @

https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkxl/strc-ren.mkxl#l118

So there's no way to break out of the box even with `\defineheadalternative[...][alternative=somewhere]`.

This also sheds light onto [ConTeXt LMTX: Offset on page titles with MetaPost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603273/context-lmtx-offset-on-page-titles-with-metapost)